# What is an ActiveRecord Rails Relation really?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I was trying to understand some of the internals of Rails Relations, in order to use them effectively in queries. Therefore, I opened up a console and did some tests:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :036 > Skill.where(:second_class => 'Wealth Ranger').map {|att| att.class}
 => [Skill(id: integer, name: string, description: string, second_class: string, third_class: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)]
```

Now, I would not expect that output. I would expect something like Relation or something similar. But it seems like it traverses every attribute and produces the type for each one.

What is a Relation in Ruby's terms really? Is it a totally custom structure? If so, are there similarities between hashes and arrays, or should it be considered like a totally custom structure?

EDIT:

After some more testing, it seems like it just contains objects of that class. Is that how it operates?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough

Comment: It's a regular class where to_s has been overridden to display the attributes.

Comment: i've already watched that, pretty good indeed, but it mostly describes relations without giving too much info on what happens with objects.

Comment: michaeltomer, this makes good sense thanx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ActiveRecord's [Relation class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) in Rails 3 is really just a layer on top of [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel). It handles collecting parameters for "lazy loading" and Rails' simplified query methods (compared to straight Arel).

The best description I've seen of it's inner workings is on [Ernie Miller's blog](https://ernie.io/2010/05/11/activerecord-relation-vs-arel/). He wrote [meta_search](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search) and [meta_where](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where) so he knows what he's talking about.